# Removing all elements from a page except those contained within an array and their parents/children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of elements I would like to keep on the page that I generated this way. The tricky part is that I need to preserve these elements parents and children.

```
var maps = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=map]")
```

I'd like to use jQuery's filter to remove all divs except those contained in the array from the page. I can't quite get it it to work though. I tried:

```
var all = $("div").get()

$(all)
  .filter(function( index ) {
      return $.inArray(this, maps) === -1;
  }).remove()
```

That removed every element from the page. I figured that it was eliminating parent divs and their children regardless of whether the children were desired. I tried putting another filter function within the function, adding some nested conditionals, but it started to become a huge nonfunctional mess. Is there a more elegant way to do this? I don't necessarily need to use `.filter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of it may be that you are not returning a value from your filter function.

But if I understand you correctly, you can just look at the element and all of its contents:

```
$(all)
  .filter(function( index ) {
      $this = $(this);
      return !($this.is("[id^=map]") || $this.find("[id^=map]").length > 0);
  }).remove()
```

Comment: Deleting the return was a typo. I edited the question to show the function that deleted everything. This is the answer I was looking for though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using complex css selectors in the first place, like this:

```
$('div:not(div:has(.keep), div.keep)').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e_neko/k0bq6gzx/
This locates required elements and removes others in one pass.

Comment: This is good, but I'm looking for div elements that contain the word map in the class title. The has selector doesn't support regex.

Comment: Perhaps in vanilla css it doesn't. In jQuery, it works: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/e_neko/k0bq6gzx/2/)